# C - Why my variable is not destroyed?

Tags: c, static

I discover C language (I am from javascript), I have this simple kind of script

```
#include "stdio.h"

int rand(){
  int numb;
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
  {
    numb++;
  }
  return numb;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  int a = rand();
  int b = rand();
  printf("%i , %i\n", a, b);
  return 0;
}
```

My question is why am I obtaining the same result (4,8) as if the variable were declarated as static & initialized to 0 ?

```
static int numb = 0;
```

I am not really sure about understand very well the scope of variables :s

Thanks !

Comment: You're not initializing `numb`. And it won't retain it's value between calls unless it's declared `static`.

Comment: And is not written as static.

Comment: Undefined behavior at `numb++`. Once you trigger UB, there's not much of a point in asking why questions.

Comment: You are lucky or unlucky. Depends on your point of view. It appears to happen that it is using the same memory. This is not guaranteed

Comment: the `numb` in `int rand()` will shadow your `static int numb` and that method will always return `3`.

Comment: BTW, `rand` is a standard library function.

Comment: Use `unsigned char numb;` to get rid of _undefined behavior_ (UB).  Yet that will still not make for very random numbers.

Comment: The standard syntax for including standard headers uses angle brackets: `#include <stdio.h>`.  Reserve double quotes for project-specific headers, not standard headers.

Comment: `rand()` is a well known system function and it s poor programing practice to write a function with the same name as a system function.

Comment: when the parameters to the `main()` function are not going to be used, then the signature for `main()` should be: `int main( void )`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The program has undefined behavior because the local variable `numb` is not initialized and in general has indeterminate value.

The result you have is explained the following way. It seems that when the function was called the first time the memory allocated for the variable stored zeroes.

When the function was called the second time it occurred so that the function used the same memory for the variable with the automatic storage duration though in general it is not necessary that the same address for the variable will be used.

According to the C Standard (6.2.4 Storage durations of objects)

> 1 An object has a storage duration that determines its lifetime. There
>   are four storage durations: static, thread, automatic, and
>   allocated...

and

> 6 For such an object that does not have a variable length array type,
>   its lifetime extends from entry into the block with which it is
>   associated until execution of that block ends in any way. (Entering an
>   enclosed block or calling a function suspends, but does not end,
>   execution of the current block.) If the block is entered recursively,
>   a new instance of the object is created each time. The initial value
>   of the object is indeterminate. If an initialization is specified for
>   the object, it is performed each time the declaration or compound
>   literal is reached in the execution of the block; **otherwise, the
>   value becomes indeterminate each time the declaration is reached**.

And at last (J.2 Undefined behavior)

> — The value of an object with automatic storage duration is used while
>   it is indeterminate (6.2.4, 6.7.9, 6.8).

Comment: The coincidence of using the same memory location is higher for smaller codes such as the example.

Comment: Ok so I understand that the complier choose the exact same adress each time I call the "rand" function & because there is already a value it point on it. So the scope of the variable is the main function ? I mean the value is cleared at the end of the program , that's it?

Comment: @nodeover The scope of the variable is the outer block scope of the function foo. Each time the function is running a new object numb is created. The lifetime of the object corresponds to the execution of the code block.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Sorry I wanted to ask, when the memory case will be cleared of the value ? , ok the variable scope does not persist between two call of function, but the value seems to still persist in the memory, so when the memory address will be free ?

Comment: @nodeover The memory can be used by some other function. It so occurs that due to the fact that your program is simple the memory is not used by some other function.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is why am I obtaining the same result (4,8) as if the
>   variable where declared as static & initialized to 0 ?

It is undefined behaviour (UB). Your observation is mere coincidence. Compile it with another compiler or on a different architecture and the results may differ.

You have to initialize the integer in the function yourself.

Comment: he asks if the variable numb in the function is declared as static and initialised to zero. He wonders why it is not assigned zero every time the function is called

Comment: That is not how I understood it, read again "as if the variable where declarated as static & initialized to 0" - `as if`. I believe the OP understands the notion of static a bit. He is not acquainted so much with UB I guess.

Comment: and the function looks like this `int rand(){
  static int numb = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
  {
    numb++;
  }
  return numb;
}`. He asks why again 4 and 8. The answer is: the static variables declared  in functons are initialised only ones and they keep their value, when the function is called again

Comment: That is not correct. Look at the question. The function is defined right there.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `rand()`, the `numb` variable is allocated on the data stack and the stack pointer is increased.

When the function is over and you return to `main`, the allocated data stack is released, and the stack pointer is decreased (the value on the actual memory remains intact).

When you recall `rand()`, the `numb` variable is again allocated on the data stack, on its previous location. It is not initialized, so the previous value is still there...

Comment: The explanation is not bad, but is just the implementation. It is UB.

Comment: @Mat - it does not have to be stored on the stack. It can be stored in the registers. But the effect is the same - the initial value is random :)

Answer (score -2):

For downvoters: it is all in the C standard.

3 different cases

1.Undefined behaviour

```
int foo(){
  int numb;
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
  {
    numb++;
  }
  return numb;
}
```

UB - nothing to explain. Anything can happen

2.Automatic initialised variable

```
int foo(){
  int numb = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
  {
    numb++;
  }
  return numb;
}
```

`numb` is initialised to zero every time the function is called and destroyed on exit.

3.Static initialised variable

```
int foo(){
  static int numb = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
  {
    numb++;
  }
  return numb;
}
```

The variable is initialised only one time and keeps its value. The scope of static automatic variables is identical to that of automatic variables, i.e. it is local to the block in which it is defined - in this case the function `foo`, but the value is kept during the program lifetime. Those variables are initialised only once, and keep their value between the calls. if the static automatic variable is not initialised - it will be initialised during the startup procedures to the default value - which is implementation defined (exept the initial values)(usually the .bss segment and initialised to zero).

source: C standard

> All objects with static storage duration shall be initialized (set to
>   their initial values) before program startup. The manner and timing of
>   such initialization are otherwise unspecified.

-

> An object whose identifier is declared without the storage-class
>   specifier
>   _Thread_local, and either with external or internal linkage or with the storage-class specifier static, has static storage duration. Its
>   lifetime is the entire execution of the program and its stored value
>   is initialized only once, prior to program startup.

-

> All the expressions in an initializer for an object that has static or
>   thread storage duration shall be constant expressions or string
>   literals.

Comment: In 2 it specifically is not actively destroyed (what ever that would mean) when it goes out of scope, hence the observed behavior.

Comment: @Ilja Everilä - actually - they are - as the stack pointers are restored at the function exit, so their storage is actively deallocated . And they are created actively  on entry by allocating the space for them on the stack. Of course sometimes they do not even have a physical representation in the memory, as compiler tries to keep them in the registers. It is best noticeable on the "register rich" RISC machines. But it also means destroyed as the registers where they were kept are getting reused

Comment: We're speaking of different things, using the same term. I understood your post to mean that "destroying" meant for example zeroing of space gone out of scope, or similar, which of course is not done, at least by compilers I've used. As I see it, going out of scope is not the same thing as destroying, which I understand more akin to deletion in languages such as C++ (we have destructors). The word "destroy" is not used in relation to scope in the C standard.

Comment: @Ilja Everilä I do not agree. It is destroyed as the storage occupied is freed or register is added to available pool.  The standard means that the automatic storage objects with no specified storage exist only in the scope they were declared. So they are created on entry and destroyed on exit.

Comment: Reading further, I think you're wrong about initialization of a static "automatic variable", or I've missed something. The rules for initialization of an object with static or thread storage duration specify that an object with arithmetic type is initialized to zero (6.7.9p10), not to an implementation defined value. "but the value is kept during the program / thread lifetime" in relation to static is also confusing and would seem to mix static and thread-local.

Comment: No - the objecy exists in the program / thread scope, but the symbol (name) exists in the scope where it was declared. Try what the value of pointer and what  dereferences `p` in this example : `int *p;

int foo(void)
{
 static int x = 0;
 p = &x;
 for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  x++;
 }
 return x;
}`

Comment: "An object whose identifier is declared without the storage-class specifier _Thread_local, and either with external or internal linkage or with the storage-class specifier static, has static storage duration. Its lifetime is the **entire execution of the program** and its stored value is initialized only once, prior to program startup." Different story for threads and _Thread_local.

Comment: Threads a quite specific and will be quite difficult to discuss this problem here. Let's forget the threads as it is not the topic of my answer.

Comment: What problem? I'm trying to point out that your current wording might lead someone to think that a static object's lifetime might be tied to threads, which it is not (yes, a program is a thread and all that). Not mentioning threads at all in relation to static would've been a lot more clear. And the answer still also, as far as I know, incorrectly states that a static arithmetic object without an explicit initializer is initialized to an implementation specified value.

Comment: @Ilja Everilä so you do not know. From the C standard: `All objects with static storage duration shall be initialized (set to their
initial values) before program startup. The manner and timing of such initialization are
otherwise unspecified.` I hope that it ends this discussion about initialisation of static objects.

Comment: I'm aware of the part you quoted and fail to see why you had to quote it - or in other words so I don't know what? The timing  of initialization was not the subject, but your answer's wording including threads in relation to static, which you seem to have fixed. Now you only incorrectly state that the implicit initialization of static objects is implementation defined.

Comment: I see that you added the "(exept the initial values)", which would seem to fix that issue, but the wording could still use a lot of editing.